# NSDateFormater mysql "style" date formatting

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios, nsdate

I'm getting from my webapp date and time in format:

> 2012-02-23T23:25:22Z

I tried with different formats but without success.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"];
```

How to setup NSDateFormater to get this string into NSDate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

But what your Z represents here.. I suppose it's not a timezone

Comment: @kondormit.. for good resource of date formatter use this [link](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/date-formatters-examples-take-2.html)

Answer (score 2):

You are using an [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) date time.

Apple uses this [recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

```
[rfc3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
[rfc3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```